# Why is there a tag called "untagged"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why is there a tag called [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)? Can't you just not add any tags? What's the point? Can we delete it? It is basically useless. Why would you create a tag like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions become [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) automatically when they lose their last remaining tag.  This happens sometimes when a question is migrated, or when a tag is removed from the site as a whole.

It's useful, too:

1. You can [check the tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) to find untagged questions (so you can re-tag them).
2. You can [create a filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/143075/untagged-ell) that notifies you via email every time a new untagged question appears.

In other words, this tag helps you make sure every question is tagged.  This is a good thing.